# Jquery Mobile : Managing data-roles in ASP.NET Master pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, templates, jquery-mobile, master-pages

I am currently using Master pages to hold most of my pages content.

Each data-role section has it's own editable region as below.

```
<div id="Page" data-role="page">
    <%-- Start Header --%>
    <div data-role="header">
        <%-- Header data removed for brevity --%>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" RunAt="Server"/>
    </div>
    <%-- End Header --%>

    <%-- Start Main Content --%>
    <div data-role="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" RunAt="Server"/>
    </div>
    <%-- End Main Content --%>

    <%-- Start Footer --%>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <%-- Footer data removed for brevity --%>
    </div>
    <%-- End Footer --%>
</div>
```

I am increasing realizing that many features require a **unique** data-role="page" **ID**

**QUESTION**

I am interested in efficient ways to be able to call the page id from a content page without having to apply all the below code to every page. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your question well "_able to call the page id from a content page_". You want to create pages dynamically and inject contents into them dynamically?

Comment: Hi again Omar, this part <div id="Page" data-role="page"> is in my master page. So every page currently uses the same id with dynamic content. I want to be able to have a unique <div id="Page" data-role="page"> on every page which I assume is the correct way to use jquery mobile. I want to do this while maintaining my master page structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but in the master page, set your page div id to a variable from the codebehind:

```
<div id="<%= ThePageID %>" data-role="page">
```

Then in each individual aspx page that uses the master page, setup a public string variable in the codebehind called ThePageID set to the desired ID e.g.:

```
public string ThePageID = "AboutPage";
```

Comment: Thanks @ezanker. It's a good idea. I will give it a try and let you know.